# What are the poetic features of this poem?

Tags: poetry

What are the poetic features of this poem?

[image]

And how can I know or determine the metrical beat in stanzas?

Comment: You probably mean "lines", not "stanzas": a stanza is a group of lines, usually with a distinct rhythmic and rhyme pattern which is repeated from  stanza to stanza.

Answer (score 5):

It's your basic tetrameter lyric, but line 7 is a standard English pentameter --five feet, but still four stresses. It's largely iambic, except for an odd spondee in line 10, and there's a strong trochaic feel to the first foot of most lines. Initial trochees are quite ordinary in English verse, but in this case  it's probably not a deliberate effect but mere amateurism.

As for how to recognize meter: just read lots of meter-based poetry (which is  mostly poetry written before about 1930, when poets stopped writing to meter), and read it **out loud**—if the poet knows her business the stresses will be the same as in ordinary speech. Once you've got it where it sounds right you can mechanically extract the traditional "feet" by counting how many stresses there are, and you can name the feet by counting how many syllables occur between stresses. It's a pretty useless analysis, but teachers like it.

Comment: I have another question, can you tell me how I can apply carter's (1999) three main models of literariness in this poem .. they told us that we should discuss in the lite of formalism and Carter's three main models of literariness

Comment: @ms.crystal I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Carter's work.

Comment: oh :(( , ok no problem